# Can I safely remove banned names from WordPress?

Tags: multisite, permalinks, blog

The banned names list for permalinks appears to be an editable list. Can I remove any of these names?

[image: http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2013/oct/07/fbi-bitcoin-pranked-silk-road?INTCMP=ILCNETTXT3487]

My particular question pertains to "blog." I would like to use is as a name for a network / multisite that I am installing.

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, thought I couldn't vote since I was new to this Stack. Thanks. The answer is excellent. Marked it as the winner.

Comment: Thanks, no competition though.. Have a look at [Privileges](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to get an first overview what you can or can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slug blog is reserved for the main/root site of a wp multisite setup. In short, *I do **not** recommend trying to use it for something else* - it only produces trouble.
The slug is hardcoded in some places, so you would have to do some hacky fixes to get around that. Which isn't a guarantee you won't have problems after all. Besides that it's almost certain that those adjustments won't survive the next update, so you have to do it all over again.
I could describe how to do it or link you to some how-to's, tutorials out there, but I decided against it, because it's just **not advisable** to do that. So if you really want to try it, you have to find the information yourself - here or on the net.

**Note:**
Above explanation refers to a *sub-folder* installation of wordpress multisite, if you are using a *subdomain* installation you should be able to use http://blog.example.ext without any problems. In the latter case you can safely remove blog from the banned names.